# Why the Groovy jar be referenced in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

My project doesn't reference the `groovy-all-1.8.3.jar`, and the jar is not in the maven dependency tree and `.classpath` file.

When the project is imported to Eclipse, it notices that the `groovy-all-1.8.3.jar` is referenced.
How can the jar be referenced?

Answer (score 0):

In the Maven Project put the following dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And run `mvn clean install` , It solves your problem.

Comment: I do not want to reference the jar. Why it be referenced, and how?

Comment: @user3171788 If your project need it, You have to refer it else it wont solve your problem.

Comment: My project does not need the jar. I do not understand how it be referenced~

Comment: @nuaa_tiger , What exactly you need?

Comment: My poor English~, I do not want the jar be referenced and I did not reference the jar through maven, but the Eclipse notices me there is a reference to the jar. The .classpath file also has no configration about this jar. Where is the reference come from? I hope you can understand me~ thank you for your help!

Comment: it is good idea to add the error here. until unless you run groovy/grails stuff in your eclipse it will not look for it